# Linq - choose permission rows optimistically

Tags: c#, linq

I have a situation here; an user is attached to more than 1 role like showed in json below

```
[
    {
        "userid" : 1,
        "roleid" : 1
    },
    {
        "userid" : 1,
        "roleid" : 2
    }
]
```

and each role contains many permissions on features (json below)

```
[
    {
        "roleid" : 1,
        "FeatureName": "AddUser",
        "Accessible": true,
    },
    {
        "roleid" : 1,
        "FeatureName": "AddEmp",
        "Accessible": true,
    },
    {
        "roleid" : 2,
        "FeatureName": "AddUser",
        "Accessible": false,
    },
    {
        "roleid" : 2,
        "FeatureName": "AddEmp",
        "Accessible": false,
    }
]
```

I need a linq query which choose choose best permission list for that user.
I have currently getting below list (in Json)

```
[
    {
        "accessid": 1,
        "roleid" : 1,
        "userid" :1,
        "FeatureName": "AddUser",
        "Accessible": true,
    },
    {
        "accessid": 2,
        "roleid" : 2,
        "userid" :1,
        "FeatureName": "AddUser",
        "Accessible": false,
    },
    {
        "accessid": 3,
        "roleid" : 1,
        "userid" :1,
        "FeatureName": "AddEmp",
        "Accessible": true,
    },
    {
        "accessid": 4,
        "roleid" : 2,
        "userid" :1,
        "FeatureName": "AddEmp",
        "Accessible": false,
    },
    {
        "accessid": 5,
        "roleid" : 1,
        "userid" :1,
        "FeatureName": "AddRoles",
        "Accessible": false,
    }
]
```

what I want now is just 1 set of optimistic permission set for a user as below

```
[
    {
        "accessid": 1,
        "roleid" : 1,
        "userid" :1,
        "FeatureName": "AddUser",
        "Accessible": true,
    },
    {
        "accessid": 3,
        "roleid" : 1,
        "userid" :1,
        "FeatureName": "AddEmp",
        "Accessible": true,
    },
    {
        "accessid": 5,
        "roleid" : 1,
        "userid" :1,
        "FeatureName": "AddRoles",
        "Accessible": false,
    }
]
```

PS: I don't bother about roleid being missed in end json.
I tried many linqs but couldn't arrive at desired json. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "I tried many linqs..." You're more likely to get an answer if you show _what_ you have tried and how it failed.

Comment: btw: do you use any query provider for json or how do you (de-)serialize it? Do you have data classes for this json or is all this part of the question?

Comment: Json format is majorly for understanding purpose. No I don't need any json converter. And the question is not about json. I just need a linq query to achieve this. And the linqs I tried are not near also, I'm unable to query or compare the values of different rows. which is needed here.

Comment: So you do have a data class representing the connection userID/roleID, a dataclass for the connection roleID/featureaccess, and probably arrays or lists of these two, and the linq query should work on these? I'm just trying to clarify your question and what kind of answer you expect....(though SO is no code-writing service, but many users like writing linq-queries for free if at least the target is clear)

Comment: What if the user have none access? In such case, do you expect no record in the result, or a list with all FeatureName but Accessible=false?

Comment: Yes, I do have all the dataclasses like userroles (users and roles), permissions, access. the linq query is something like this. from ur in db.UserRoles
 join rp in db.Role_Permissions on ur.RoleId equals rp.RoleId
 join fp in db.FPermissions on rp.PermissionId equals fp.PermissionId
 where fp.Active == true and ur.userid=1 select new {......}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a class name `Access` as model of result

```
public class Access
{
    public int accessid { get; set; }
    public int roleid { get; set; }
    public int userid { get; set; }
    public string FeatureName { get; set; }
    public bool Accessible { get; set; }
}
```

And also you had found a way to query the `Access` for an user, then you could use below LINQ to optimise the result

**EDIT** updated so the result contain denial(`Accessible=false`) result

```
 var optimised = from o in accesses
                 group o by new { o.userid, o.FeatureName } into g
                 select new Access()
                 {
                     userid = g.Key.userid,
                     FeatureName = g.Key.FeatureName,
                     //OrderByDescending put the true before the false
                     Accessible = g.OrderByDescending(t => t.Accessible).First().Accessible,

                     //you might want to comment the accessid and roleid
                     accessid = g.First().accessid,
                     roleid = g.First().roleid,
                 };
```

Comment: It can't be like this, since accesssible=true, since I don't know if the result only contains false, it must say false. I'm updating the question( the json ) for you.

Comment: Thank you very much @Evan Huang. This directly didn't solve but the eye opener was "orderby will sort true and false". And the First() didn't work, but FirstOrDefault() worked for me.